# how to animate images in a video

Tags: animation, opencv, video-processing, javacv

has someone a soultion to create a videosequence which show a animated image?
With animatied i mean:

- an images which rotaided from angle x to angle y in z seconds
- an image which zoomed in/out by factor x in z seconds

something like this: [Test zoom with Opencv and C++](http://youtu.be/N3n4oF5PXVA)
The result will be saved as videofile on harddisk (no display by creation)

In worst case i can transform each image stept by step ...but....

greetings

Comment: actually what you are worried, image transformation or writing to a video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> an images which rotaided from angle x to angle y in z seconds

[Affine transformation](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html) should help you with that.

> an image which zoomed in/out by factor x in z seconds

Setting ROI and resizing should help you with that.

> In worst case i can transform each image stept by step ...but....

But what? This is the only solution using OpenCV. Alternatively you can use video and image edtitors.